# Почему не добавляется дата в таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO student(date) VALUES('$date')");
```

[php http://savepic.net/8830189.png](http://savepic.net/8830189.png)

Comment: а что у вас в $_POST['date']

Comment: <div class="row">
   <label for="date">Дата рождения:</label> 
     <input type="date" name="date" value="1960-01-01"
   max="2100-12-31" min="1960-01-01">
  </div>

Comment: Если создать отдельную таблицу и отправлять запрос туда, то оно отправляется, А сюда почему то нет, проверил имена, все правильно

Comment: можете выложить весь свой скрипт?

Comment: Извините я уже все исправил, был какой-то баг или незн)
Решил путем пересозданием таблицы)спс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в таблице `student` для всех столбцов нет значений по умолчанию и не разрешены `NULL`. Поэтому есть три варианта:

1. Задать для столбцов значение по умолчанию.
2. Разрешить `NULL` для столбцов.
3. При `INSERT`-е указывать все поля, а не только `date`.